# How do I make the parent dirty when I change a hasMany/belongsTo relationship in Ember-Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

My main problem with Ember Data, right now, is that when I change a relationship (hasMany or belongsTo), the parent doesn't get dirty.

I need this because:

- I'm depending on the `isDirty` property to show a save/cancel button
- hasMany and belongsTo ids are sent with the parent, so the parent in fact *IS* dirty.

Also, when I rollback the parent, only the belongsTo relationships are reverted. The hasMany models stay the same.

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/866) that talks about a `dirtyRecordsForHasManyChange` hook, but that doesn't seem to exist in Ember Data v1 (v1.0.0-beta.3, which is what I'm using).

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

For a belongsTo I added an observer.

For example in my I have Person with a belongsTo Province.  On my form I have an ember select for the provinces.  In the Person model I add this observer...

```
provinceChanged: function() {
  this.send('becomeDirty');
}.observes('province')
```

I too am depending on isDirty for showing/hiding Save/Cancel buttons, and while that observer does a fine job at marking the record as dirty, if I hit cancel, I do the rollback, but I also need to mark the record clean. I do this in the Person controller on my cancel action.

```
cancel: function() {
  this.get('model').rollback();
  this.set('isEditing', false);
  this.get('model').adapterWillCommit();
  this.get('model').adapterDidCommit();
}
```

This all seems to be working quite well.

For hasMany on another project we used a computed property on the controller.

```
isThisOrChildrenDirty: function() {
  return this.get('isDirty') || this.get('authors').get('isDirty');
}.property('isDirty','authors.@each.isDirty')
```

Then instead of checking isDirty we check isThisOrChildrenDirty.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hey spDuchamp, i've tried your first code sample on a hasMany relationship. It works, but my parent record becomes stained immediately after loading a parent record with children. I wonder whether there's a way to stain the parent record only when a child is changed, not when the relationship is initially populated.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.get('model').send('becomeDirty');
```

That should do this trick. Just send becomeDirty to the parent model.